# Delphi: TIdTCPClient disconnect don't close the connection

Tags: delphi, tcp, indy, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm investigation on a growing of active TCP connection.

Seems `TIdTCPClient.Disconnect` don't close connection.

This is a sample project

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  IdTCPClient;

var
  FClient: TIdTCPClient;
begin
  try
    FClient := TIdTCPClient.Create();
    FClient.Connect('LOCALHOST', 6379);

    FClient.Disconnect;
    FClient.Free;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Opening this console application multiple times cause a growing of the connection

```
netstat -na | find "6379"
```

[image]

Side note: I'm on Berlin 10, Windows 7 (but is the same on Windows 10)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Disconnect()` *is* closing the connection.  The `TIME_WAIT` state is normal TCP behavior.

Whichever peer is first to *actively* close the TCP connection (in this case, your client), its socket endpoint goes into the `TIME_WAIT` state, which is a safety feature of TCP to discard any stray packets remaining in that connection.  The endpoint will be fully released after a few moments once `TIME_WAIT` times out.

On the other peer, the one *passively* receiving notification of the closure, its socket endpoint goes into the `CLOSE_WAIT` state instead, and is released once the closure is `ACK`ed by the other peer.  There is no `TIME_WAIT` on that side.

See [TIME_WAIT and its design implications for protocols and scalable client server systems](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/01/time-wait-and-its-design-implications-for-protocols-and-scalable-servers.html), which goes into a very lengthy discussion of what `TIME_WAIT` is, why it exists, and how to work with it effectively.

Answer (score 1):

The connection is closed. `TIME_WAIT` indicates that local endpoint (this side) has closed the connection.

Ref: https://superuser.com/questions/173535/what-are-close-wait-and-time-wait-states

Comment: "*The other side has not yet acknowledged the closing*" - that is not what TIME_WAIT means. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33178079/65863). In fact, you can't get into `TIME_WAIT` *until* the other side has acknowledged the close.